# How to remove quotation marks in C

Tags: c, string, strtok

How can we remove quotation marks, for example if we have: `"film"` and we want to return `film`
My code:

```
char* remove_quotes(char* s1) {
    if (s1[0] == '"' && s1[strlen(s1) - 1] == '"') {
        s1[0] = '\0';
        s1[strlen(s1) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    return s1;
}
```

It should be something like that?

Comment: _If_ you get a match, the return value should be `s1 + 1`, so after the _second_ `strlen` line, add: `++s1;` to point past the left quote [that is now 0x00].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `s1[0] = '\0';` will prevent `strlen(s1)` from returning proper value.
- You should return `s1 + 1` instead of `s1` to skip the first quotation mark (or space that a quotation mark was there).

Try this:

```
char* remove_quotes(char* s1) {
    if (s1[0] == '"' && s1[strlen(s1) - 1] == '"') {
        s1[strlen(s1) - 1] = '\0';
        return s1 + 1;
    }
    return s1;
}
```

If you want both `"` to be removed from the original string, you can shift the contents of memory via [`memmove()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) instead of shifting the pointer. (Don't use `strcpy()` nor `memcpy()` because copying to overlapped destination is not supported by them)

```
char* remove_quotes(char* s1) {
    size_t len = strlen(s1);
    if (s1[0] == '"' && s1[len - 1] == '"') {
        s1[len - 1] = '\0';
        memmove(s1, s1 + 1, len - 1);
    }
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do you check in the main, if I want for example `char* example = "film";` it's without quotation marks and if I wrote `char* example = ""film"";` , It will be an error

Comment: 1. Modifying string literal is prohibited. You have to prepare a modifyable array. 2. You have to use an escape sequence to put quotation marks in string literals. It should be: `char example[] = "\"film\"";`

Comment: The first `"` is stile there, for example if the string is `"film"` it will return `"film`, maybe do you know why?

Comment: @Xavi No, [it *returns* `film`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qlvpzGErOmM7eNMf). The reason for not removing the first `"` is that I thought it won't be seen because the returned pointer is shifted to point the next character of the quotation mark.

Comment: There is a way to fix it? Because when I use it, it return "film

Comment: @Xavi Added that.

Answer (score 0):

The removal function is relatively simple. Just have two pointers.

````
#include <stdio.h>

char *strdelch(char *str, char ch)
{
    char *current = str;
    char *tail = str;

    while(*tail)
    {
        if(*tail == ch)
        {
            tail++;
        }
        else
        {
            *current++ = *tail++;
        }
    }
    *current = 0;
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hell`o` ```w`o``r`l```d`!```";

    printf("%s\n", strdelch(str, '`'));
}
````

https://godbolt.org/z/M7n8EExoc